# Vertices of a Rotated Polyhedron

Tags: graphics3d, regions, computational-geometry

I am attempting to geometrically transform a polyhedron (namely rotate and translate the polyhedron in global coordinates) and than find the new vertices. Here is what I have so far, but I am stuck at how to get the new vertices since there doesn't seem to be  a nice function for it.

```
θz = 90 °;
rotationaxis = {1, 1, 0};
position = {1, 1, 0};
graphics = Graphics3D[GeometricTransformation[GeometricTransformation[
 N[PolyhedronData["SnubCube", "GraphicsComplex"]], 
 RotationMatrix[θz, rotationaxis]], 
 TranslationTransform[position]]]
```

Any assistance is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`TransformedRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedRegion) instead. Start with a region object:

```
region = PolyhedronData["SnubCube", "Region"];
```

Transform the region using [`TransformedRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedRegion):

```
transformed = TransformedRegion[
    region,
    TranslationTransform[position] @* RotationTransform[θz, rotationaxis]
]
```

[image]

Get the vertices using [`MeshCoordinates`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshCoordinates):

```
MeshCoordinates[transformed]
```

> {{-0.179457, 0.69909, 0.569122}, {1.03684, 0.158297, 
>     1.04678}, {0.356908, -0.120748, 0.368676}, {0.500478, 0.978135, 
>     1.24722}, {1.8417, 0.963156, -1.04678}, {1.30091, 
>     2.17946, -0.569122}, {1.02187, 1.49952, -1.24722}, {2.12075, 
>     1.64309, -0.368676}, {0.69909, -0.179457, -0.569122}, {0.963156, 1.8417, 
>     1.04678}, {-0.28744, 1.32846, -0.200445}, {1.94969, 0.333786, 
>     0.678102}, {0.158297, 1.03684, -1.04678}, {2.17946, 1.30091, 
>     0.569122}, {1.66621, 0.050314, -0.678102}, {0.67154, 2.28744, 
>     0.200445}, {-0.120748, 0.356908, -0.368676}, {1.49952, 1.02187, 
>     1.24722}, {1.32846, -0.28744, 0.200445}, {0.050314, 1.66621, 
>     0.678102}, {0.978135, 0.500478, -1.24722}, {1.64309, 2.12075, 
>     0.368676}, {0.333786, 1.94969, -0.678102}, {2.28744, 0.67154, -0.200445}}

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use the transformations on the coordinates directly without using `GeometricTransformation`:

```
gc = N@PolyhedronData["SnubCube", "GraphicsComplex"];
vertices = RotationMatrix[θz, rotationaxis].# & /@ 
  (TranslationTransform[position] /@ gc[[1]]) ;
gc2 = GraphicsComplex[vertices, gc[[2]]];
Normal[gc2] == Normal[graphics[[1]]] /. Polygon[x_, __] :> Polygon[x]
```

> True

```
Graphics3D[{gc2, Red, PointSize[Large], Point@vertices}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use [`Normal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html) in two ways:

2. You can wrap `GeometricTransformation` with `Normal` (which, *when possible, will perform the transformations explicitly*):

```
graphics2 = Graphics3D[Normal @ GeometricTransformation[GeometricTransformation[
       N[PolyhedronData["SnubCube", "GraphicsComplex"]], 
       RotationMatrix[θz, rotationaxis]], 
      TranslationTransform[position]]] ;
vertices2 = DeleteDuplicates[Join @@ Cases[graphics2[[1]], Polygon[x_, ___] :> x, ∞]];
Sort[vertices2] == Sort[vertices]
```

> True

3. You can convert `GraphicsComplex` *into ordinary lists of graphics primitives and directives* using `Normal`:

```
vertices3 = DeleteDuplicates[Join @@ Cases[Normal[graphics][[1]], 
  Polygon[x_, ___] :> x, ∞]]; 
Sort[vertices3] == Sort[vertices]
```

> True

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: @Novice, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.